# Undelegate single event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am having trouble stopping a click event on a dom element in a UL, essentially in the `itemClicked` method I want to undelegate the click event on the single element. When an item in a list is clicked, however that item still fires a click event despite have the none value. Is there a way to use undelegate for just the individual element clicked? I am at a loss as to why and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
App.Views.AttributeSelectorView = Backbone.View.extend({

  itemClicked: function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    this.trigger('itemClicked', $target.data('attr'), $target.text());

    this.undelegateEvents();
  }, 
  events: {
    'click [role=menuitem]': 'itemClicked'
  }
});   


 attributeSelectorView.on('itemClicked', function(attribute, display){
    // .remove attribute
    query.add({
      attribute: attribute,
      display: display
    }, {
      merge: true
    });
  });
```

Comment: itemClicked is not a DOM event, it's a backbone event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [stopListening](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening), `it Tell an object to stop listening to events`.

```
itemClicked: function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    this.trigger('itemClicked', $target.data('attr'), $target.text());

    this.stopListening();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `pointer-events` attribute in the click handler itself. The click event has already happened by the time you change its `target` element's style.

You need to set the property before a click occurs for it to take effect.

Or, if you know which elements you want to ignore clicks on, you could add logic in your click handler:

```
itemClicked: function(e) {

  if(!shouldIgnoreThisTarget) {
    this.trigger('...')
  }
}
```

In many ways this is better. It brings the click behaviour into one place and reduces coupling between your CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: When you create the `li` element (probably in your view's `render` method, or maybe from a template or HTML file), add a class called something descriptive like `no-click-events`. Then add a rule to your CSS: `.no-click-events { pointer-events: none; }`.

Answer (score -1):

`pointer-events` only effects style - so it won't affect the functionality of an element (ie. javascript events).

If you want to prevent the default click behavior in javascript, you can [return false](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link4) from the click handler, or set [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) to true